# Issue with swapping program, the program crashes

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to make a program that scans 3 ints and then passes them through a function that sort them by this way- the biggest number will be at 'num3', the second will be at 'num2' and the lowest one will be at 'num1' but for some reason the program crashes when it gets to the sort function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b);
void changer(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3);

int main()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;

    printf("Please enter your value for 'num1': ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    getchar();

    printf("Please enter your value for 'num2': ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    getchar();

    printf("Please enter your value for 'num3': ");
    scanf("%d", &num3);

    printf("\nYour nums before- \n");
    printf("num1 == %d\n", num1);
    printf("num2 == %d\n", num2);
    printf("num3 == %d\n", num3);

    changer(&num1, &num2, &num3);

    printf("\nYour nums after- \n");
    printf("num1 == %d\n", num1);
    printf("num2 == %d\n", num2);
    printf("num3 == %d\n", num3);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void changer(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3)
{
    if (*num1 > *num3)
    {
        swap(*num3, *num1);
    }
    else if (*num1 > *num2)
    {
        swap(*num1, *num2);
    }

    if (*num2 > *num3)
    {
        swap(*num3, *num2);
    }
}

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not dereference the pointers when you pass them to `swap()` since it takes `int *` and you would be passing `int` thus causing undefined behavior and in your case a crash. The compiler should warn about incompatible parameters.

Change every occurrence of

```
swap(*num1, *num2);
/*   ^      ^ remove these */
```

with

```
swap(num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

swap(int*, int*) expects the integer pointer to be passed in, assume the value of num1 = 0 and num2 = 2 and when you pass these values to swap(), by dereferencing you are invoking like this swap(0, 2) or on 32 bit system

> swap(0x00000000, 0x00000002)

Inside swap(int* a, int* b) you dereference the memory location 0x00000000 (not the memory pointed to by **a**) at the line,

```
int temp = *a;
```

and then you dereference 0x00000002 **b** at this line and trying to assign it to 0x00000000 (by dereferencing ***a**)

```
*a = *b;
```

You are generating

> Memory access violation condition.

which is causing the crash. Summarizing, **please do not ignore compiler warnings**. Compiler raises warning on the line where you are making swap() calls.

> 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Both functions take integer pointers (i.e., memory addresses of integers) as arguments. So, the values of the arguments `a`, `b`, `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` must ALWAYS be memory addresses of integers. In the function **`changer`**, values of the variables `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` are ALREADY memory addresses. When you write `*num1`, value of `*num1` is integer but not the memory address of an integer. So, you need to call the function **`swap`** as follows:

```
swap(num3, num1);

swap(num1, num2);

swap(num3, num2);
```